# Pywinauto focus on new dropdown

Tags: python, focus, powerbi, pywinauto, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to automate a data refresh in Power BI, based on specific parameters. In order I've adjusted the Power BI refresher script (https://github.com/dubravcik/pbixrefresher-python), based on PyWinAuto.
To adjust the parameters, I have to open and use a dropdown menu in the ribbon of Power BI and I suspect that when opening the dropdown menu, the focus is still on the main screen of PowerBI, so I cannot manipulate inside the dropdown menu.

How could I identify and focus on the dropdown menu with PyWinAuto?

(See also https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk6kS.png)

```
# Focus on the Power BI window
app = Application(backend = 'uia').connect(path = PBIDesktop.exe)
win = app.window(title_re = '.*Power BI Desktop')
win.wait("enabled", timeout = 300)
win.set_focus()
win.wait("enabled", timeout = 300)

# Open the dropdown menu with Alt+H, then Q
win.type_keys('%HQ')
# Next part doesn't work, I suspect because of no focus on the dropdown menu
win.type_keys('{DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}')
```

Comment: What I see is Ribbon toolbar. It should be similar to MS Paint example in the repo folder “examples”.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

`win.type_keys('%HQ{DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}')`